# Kubernetes API Server Healthcheck Address with kubeadm

Tags: kubernetes

I'm attempting to start a kubernetes cluster on a machine that has two ip-addresses with kubeadm v1.13.1. I'd like the kube-apiserver process to bind to one of them specifically. I've been successfull in doing this with the following configuration passed in to `kubeadm init`, but the healthcheck portion of the apiserver manifest uses the other (default route) ip-address. This causes kubelet to tear down the kube-apiserver container due to failed healthchecks.

```
kind: InitConfiguration
apiVersion: kubeadm.k8s.io/v1beta1
localApiEndpoint:
  advertiseAddress: 192.168.10.10
---
apiVersion: kubeadm.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: ClusterConfiguration
apiServer:
  certSANs:
  - 192.168.10.10
  extraArgs:
    advertise-address: 192.168.10.10
    bind-address: 192.168.10.10
controlPlaneEndpoint: 192.168.10.10:6443
```

It appears the localApiEndpoint isn't being used at all as I can put any cruft in the advertiseAddress fields without causing errors or warnings. Misspelling localApiEndpoint or advertiseAddress does cause warnings which implies I haven't misspelled these.

How can I get kubeadm to properly generate the health check section of the apiserver manifest?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I misspelled localAPIEndpoint as localApiEndpoint. Fixing the spelling fixed the issue.

Interestingly:

- localApiEndpoint - appears to be silently ignored
- localAPIEndpoint - works correctly
- localAPIEndpoints - causes a warning